# Wrong rails plural when creating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having problems with rails plurals.

I have a model named `CompanySkill` (which represents the skills owned by a company). When creating the model rails pluralizes it with `companies_skill`  instead of `company_skills`, therefore when I need to set up the `has_many :company_skills` association rails doesn't use the model.

What is the correct solution to this problem? What I thought about is to use inflections, but I don't know if it is the right solution and/or there are better solutions.

I'm generating the model from the console:

```
rails generate model CompanySkill
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20160511111048_create_companies_skill.rb
  create    app/models/company_skill.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/company_skill_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/companies_skill.yml
```

Comment: why dont u use has_many :companies_skill 
?

Comment: I could, but linguistically it is nicer to see that a Company has_many:  company_skills, because it represents the skill**S** that **A** company has

Comment: Inflections is an option, indeed. Do you have any other "skills" model in your app, besides CompanySkill? Like EmployeeSkill, maybe?

Comment: inflections is probably the right solution, but I'm surprised that it isn't using the expected inflection already.  If I create a AR class called `CompanySkill` and call `table_name` on it I get `"company_skills"`.  Where are you seeing the pluralisation?

Comment: It surprises me too, @MaxWilliams. This plural is not even a strange one.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida yes, i have a StudentSkill model too, but that pluralized correctly, i don't know why I'm having issues with this one.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'm having the issue when generating the model through console, I edited the question to include it.

Comment: *"When creating the model rails pluralizes it with companies_skill"*. That is definitely not how Rails pluralizes "company_skill". What do you mean "when creating the model"? From a generator?

Comment: What is your Rails Version? I just did `rails g model CompanySkill` and I got `company_skills`(which is correct).

Comment: My rails version is 4.2.4

Comment: It might be a bug in 4.2.4. I'm using 4.2.5 and I got the correct pluralization.

Comment: @Pavan I'm extremely new to ruby on rails and this is my high school thesis. Is changing rails version safe? Do I just change the number version in my gemfile?

Comment: You could just skip the automatic model generation, and make the files manually, or let the automatic generation run and modify the files to refer to the desired name.  The generator is just there to save you a bit of time, it's not essential.

Comment: If you are in the early stages of developing your app, then surely upgrading the rails version is beneficial(atleast you can avoid these strange bugs/behaviors).

Comment: @Fabio You showed us the output of `rails delete model ...`, where is your `rails generate model ...`?

Comment: @meagar you're totally right, I'm dumb, updated

Comment: I think i solved the problem but i don't know if im doing it right. I posted an answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options.

First of all you can override the inflector for this name. In `config/initializers/inflections.rb` add the following:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'company_skill', 'company_skills'
end
```

Alternatively, and probably the best solution, you can specify the class name on the association. In your model use something like this:

```
has_many :company_skills, class_name: 'CompanySkill'
```

Although, as other people have said, neither of these solutions should be required, since `company_skill` should be pluralised by Rails to `company_skills` by default.

Comment: This won't help, because Rails *already* inflects `company_skill` correctly. You're overriding the inflection with the *same inflection*.

Comment: Hence my preferred solution of specifying the class name

Comment: If Rails is already producing the correct pluralization, there is something else at play here. Neither specifying `class_name:` or adding a custom inflection is necessary *or correct*. They cannot fix the problem as the problem has been misrepresented.

Comment: Besides, all these solutions do NOT explain why Rails is having such a strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I fixed the problem.

I first generated the model with:

```
rails generate model CompanySkill
```

which created the model wrongly pluralized.

```
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160511111214_create_companies_skill.rb
      create    app/models/company_skill.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/company_skill_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/companies_skill.yml
```

I then edited the migration changing the table name:

```
class CreateCompaniesSkill < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :company_skills do |t|  #was :companies_skill
      t.integer :skill_id
      t.integer :company_id
      t.integer :level

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Then I finally used self.table_name in the model as suggested:

```
class CompanySkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "company_skills"
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :company_skills
  belongs_to :skill
  validates_presence_of :company
  validates_presence_of :skill
end
```

So now if from console i create a company_skill and then i do Company.first.skills I can get the skill

```
Company.first.skills
  Company Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Skill Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "skills".* FROM "skills" INNER JOIN "company_skills" ON "skills"."id" = "company_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "company_skills"."company_id" = ?  [["company_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Skill id: 1, name: "Nihil dolorum maiores et ex temporibus est. Volupt...", school_year: 2, created_at: "02/05/2016 20:09:54", updated_at: "02/05/2016 20:09:54">]>
```

If I remove self.table_name, though, I get the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'companies_skill'`

Am I doing this right?

Comment: You are correctly working around the issue, but there is no reason you should have to. Rails does not behave the way you're claiming it does, there is some other undiagnosed problem here. Even if I install Rails 4.2.4, run `rails g model Company`, `rails g model Skill` and `rails g model CompanySkill`, Rails *still* does not produce the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: @meagar ........ i had an inflection `inflect.plural "company", "companies"` .......... I'm sorry, I don't know why. Should I remove the question?

Comment: @Fabio That explains the strange behavior!

Comment: I almost raised this as an issue at rails/rails at GitHub! LOL It was something strange enough to be posted there.

Comment: In my case, this is going to help thanks! I have a model ReasonForVisit and want a table reasons_for_visit but Rails pluralizes wrong the name to reason_for_visits so I'm planning to use this strategy